# DNS Server with dnsmasq

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, debian, dnsmasq

I'm trying to set up dnsmasq as a dns server on a virtual machine running Debian. I can successfully run nslookup from another computer: `nslookup facebook.com 10.0.11.2` and the answer I get is:

```
Server:        10.0.11.2
Address:       10.0.11.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    facebook.com
Address: 173.252.110.27
```

Now when I do a lookup for a local address such as `nslookup router.domain.com 10.0.11.2` and the answer I get is `;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`

(However on the actual dns server, running a traceroute uses "router.domain.com" rather than its IP address)

My dnsmasq.conf contains:

```
address=/router.domain.com/10.0.11.2
no-resolv
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
```

and my resolv.conf contains:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search domain.com
```

What might the problem be?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left BIND enabled! Sorted now.

Answer (score 1):

So, the line in your config file:

no-resolv

tells dnsmasq to ignore the contents of your resolv.conf file. Perhaps you should comment that line out?

There's a pretty good article at:
http://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/dnsmasq#Local_Caching
that describes this.

Comment: I changed that, but still have the same problems as above.